# How to populate select list with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am novice in HTML, javaScript or jQuery, I am basically an Oracle DBA and Developer. I need to know how to populate select list with jquery.
I have created a string from database query which is as mentioned below. Now I want this to be populated in a select list.
For example I have the string like:

```
<select id="my-select" name="emplist">
<option value="7839">KING</option>
<option value="7782">CLARK</option>
<option value="7934">MILLER</option>
<option value="21">MAMUN</option></select>
```

and I like to populate the select list item
called '#SELECT_LIST' with the data above. How can I do that?
Now I want the selct item to be populated with the string.

Please respond, your answer will help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want  as an output?

Comment: Please update your question with what you've tried, what output you're getting, what output you should be getting and what research you've done on finding the fix.

Comment: `$('#SELECT_LIST').html('yourstring')` …? (Only if `#SELECT_LIST` is not a select element already - in that case, you would need to append options only of course, select elements can not be nested.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use jquery to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//init data
var arrayList = [
        {"Id": 100, "Name": "Abc"}, 
        {"Id": 200, "Name": "XYZ"}
        ];

for (var i = 0; i <= arrayList.length; i++) {
        $('#SELECT_LIST').append('<option value="' + arrayList[i].Id + '">' + arrayList[i].Name + '</option>');
    }

});
```

Comment: can there be any option to loop through the values, because in ajax call list may vary in numbers,

Comment: @HasanAlMamun: You can use a loop in this case, my friend. I will edit my answer for example :)

Comment: Thanks , I will try it, looks promising. Thank you.

Comment: @HasanAlMamun: We try together, my friend :))

Comment: Yes it's working. Thank you for the clue. But a little bit of help is needed, for each ajax call the select list needs to be newly initialized. But now it appends to the previous values.

Comment: Yes now it works perfectly, just added $("#SELECT_LIST").empty(); before the for loop; Thank you man. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @HasanAlMamun: Nice. You're so great, my friend :))

Comment: Mate this code killed me for about 15 mins. The loop needs to be LESS THAN not LESS THAN EQUAL THAN!! haha

Comment: @ShaneMonksO'Byrne: Oh, you're right. It's my mistake. Sorry for any inconvenience, my friend :D

Answer (score 12):

Using Array.prototype.forEach() and let

```
let data = [{"code":1, "name": "A"},
{"code":2, "name": "B"},
{"code":3, "name": "C"},
{"code":4, "name": "D"}];

data.forEach(function(e, i){
   $('#select-id').append($('<option></option>').val(e.code).text(e.name)); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#my-select").val("7839");
```

Maybe you can look at this.
http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/